# Receive and Register a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-broadcast

I have a Java class with a layout . i want to make a BroadcastReceiver to get the incoming calling number . How i can do this in my Activity Class :

now i am trying this :

```
    package com.example.callchecker;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.Dialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Intent;;

    public class Mark_number extends Activity {
        Context context = this ;
        Dialog D =new Dialog(context);
Button btn_dialog = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_dialog);
Button btn_dismiss = (Button) D.findViewById(R.id.btn_dismiss);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mark_number);

    private BroadcastReceiver myR = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

}
    }
```

Is this the right way OR i have to make another class that extends the BraodcastRceiver ??

```
    public class My_Receiver extends BroadcastRceiver {
```

If to make another Class then how to call it from my Main Activity ???

Comment: hi natiq: you can register your receiver in your manifest if you dont have requirement to dynamically remove listening of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define your `BroadcastReceiver` as an anonymous object (*First option*), you can only register it dynamically and it will live throughout your Application execution. When your app dies, it will be unregistered automatically (And of course you can unregister it earlier, if you want to).

However, by defining a class extending `BroadcastReceiver` in a separate file (*Second option*), you can declare it in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file, which will let you receive broadcasts even when your app is dead.

Which is better? Depends on your requirements. If you don't need to receive broadcasts while your app is closed, you can declare an anonymous object and register/unregister it dynamically (Shorter option). However, if you do need to receive broadcasts all the time, you'll have to define it in another class and declare it in the manifest.

Comment: I want to get the Phone number of incoming call even when my app is not running .. 

so you says that the second option is good for me ???

if so then who to do i register the Broadcastreceiver in AndroidManifist ??

Comment: If you want to receive broadcasts while your app is not running, the second option is a **must**. Read about receivers here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html

Answer (score 0):

the second one is the way to go!

send an intent on occourance of desired event to the class extending broadcast receiver from your main activity.

Comment: Can you please explain how to do this ??
How to call the class extending Broadcastreceiver from the main activity ???

Comment: you do it by sending an intent> declare an intent directed to the Broadcast Receiver and fire it up by startService(intent).